# Issue with Visualforce Grid Save Button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am facing issue with Custom Visualforce Grid During Save .
When i click Save Changes Button I am getting below error

> ```
> System.ListException: DML statement found null SObject at position 3
> Error is in expression '{!Save1}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page r_gridpage: Class.R_GridClass.Save1: line 24, column 1
> Class.R_GridClass.Save1: line 24, column 1
> ```

Below is my visualforce and Apex codes

Visualforce Code

```
<apex:page standardController="Student__c" extensions="R_GridClass">  
    <apex:form id="formId">
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Delete Selected Item" action="{!DeleteSelected}"/> 
        <apex:commandButton value="Add Student" action="{!AddSelected}"/> 
        <apex:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="{!Save1}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Update Selected Row" action="{!UpdateSelected}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!studentList}" var="st">
            <apex:column headerValue="Selection">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!st.Selected}"/>
            </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!st.std.First_Name__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Mobile">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!st.std.Mobile__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!st.std.Email__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Occupation">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!st.std.Occupation__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="DOJ">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!st.std.Date_of_Joining__c}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
         <!--<apex:commandButton value="Add New Student" action="{!addNew}"/><br/>-->
         <!--<apex:commandButton value="Save Records" action="{!Save}"/> --->
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Code

```
public class R_GridClass {
Public List<WrapStudent> studentList {get;set;}
    public R_GridClass(ApexPages.StandardController ctrlr)
    {
      studentList = new List<WrapStudent>();
        for (Student__c stud :[SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Mobile__c, Email__c, Date_of_Joining__c, Occupation__c FROM Student__c])
        {
           studentList.add(new WrapStudent(stud)); 
        }
    }

    public void AddSelected()
{
   studentList.add(new WrapStudent() );
}  
 public PageReference Save1()
{
List<Student__c> slist = new List<Student__c>();
for (Integer i = 0;i<studentList.size();i++)
{
 slist.add(studentList[i].std );
}
upsert slist;
 System.debug('Size of Selected List is -'+studentList.size());   
   PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage();            
   tempPage.setRedirect(true);
    return tempPage ;
}  
public PageReference DeleteSelected()
{
    List<Student__c> listToDelete = new List<Student__c>();
    for (WrapStudent wd : studentList)
    {
        if(wd.selected == true)
        {
            listToDelete.add(wd.std);
        }
    }
    if (listToDelete.size()>0)
    {

    Delete listToDelete;
        }
   PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage();            
   tempPage.setRedirect(true);
    return tempPage ;

     /*PageReference myVFPage = new PageReference('/'+'a007F000004tfiq');
         return myVFPage;*/
} 

    public PageReference UpdateSelected()
{
    List<Student__c> listToUpdate = new List<Student__c>();
    for (WrapStudent wd : studentList)
    {
        if(wd.selected == true)
        {
            listToUpdate.add(wd.std);
        }
    }
    update listToUpdate;
   PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage();            
   tempPage.setRedirect(true);
    return tempPage ;

     /*PageReference myVFPage = new PageReference('/'+'a007F000004tfiq');
         return myVFPage;*/
}  



public class WrapStudent 
{

    Public Student__c std {get;set;}
    Public Boolean selected {get;set;} 
    Public WrapStudent (Student__c s)
    {
       std = s;
       selected = false; 

    }

    Public WrapStudent ()
    {


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple really. Whenever you add a new student to the list in `AddSelected()` you call the `WrapStudent()` constructor that doesn't do anything. doesn't even create an in-memory dummy `new Student__c()`. So when you finally pull it out of the wrapper it's still null.

You can't insert null records. You can try inserting empty ones (`insert new Account()` will work and attempt to use default values, will even try to put something in Name field... as long as you don't have validation rules, required fields etc).

So that's what the error says, "DML statement found null SObject at position 3".

Either make sure that all Wrapper records do have a non-null Student__c in them or filter the nulls when building the `List<Student__c>` to save, similar to how you filter them based on the checkbox in `UpdateSelected`.